# I have added a metabox and inside it i added a secondary title and a text editor but if i write anything it does not save it or show it on my page

Tags: metabox

functions.php file:

```
function add_custom_meta_box2()
{
         add_meta_box(
                'meta-box2',
                'SD Extra Page/Post Options ',
                'custom_meta_box_markup2',
                'page',
                'normal',
                'low'
                );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box2');

function custom_meta_box_markup1(){

}

function custom_meta_box_markup2($post)
{
    global $post;
    wp_nonce_field( basename(__FILE__ ), 'custom_meta2_nonce');
    $custom_stored_meta2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sec_title', true );

    ?>
    <div>
    <div class="meta-row">
    <div class="meta-th">
      <label for="sec_title" class="sec-row-title"> Secondary ID</label>
    </div>

    <div class="meta-td">

        <input type="text" name="sec_title" id="sec_title" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $custom_stored_meta2); ?>"/>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="meta">
    <div class="meta-th">
    <span> Principle Duties</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="meta-editor">


    <?php
    $content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'principle_duties', true);
    $editor = 'principle_duties';
    $settings = array(
       'textarea_rows' => 8,
       'media_buttons' => false,
    );

    wp_editor( $content, $editor, $settings);

    ?>
    </div>

    <?php
}

function custom_meta2_save($post_id){

    //checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id);
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id);
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $POST[ 'custom_meta2_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['custom_meta2_nonce' ],basename( __FILE__)) ) ? 'true': 'false';
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
    //Exit scripts depending on save status
    if( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ){
        return;
    }

    if( isset( $POST['sec_title'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id , 'sec_title', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'sec_title'] ) );
    }

    if( isset( $POST['principle_duties'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id , 'principle_duties', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'principle_duties'] ) );
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'custom_meta2_save');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `$post` instead of `$_POST` in save function. That is why data is not saved.

You have should use :

```
$_POST[ 'custom_meta2_nonce' ]
$_POST['sec_title']
$_POST['principle_duties']
```

instead of

```
$POST[ 'custom_meta2_nonce' ]
$POST['sec_title']
$POST['principle_duties']
```

Use below code to save data :

```
function custom_meta2_save($post_id){
    //checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id);
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id);
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'custom_meta2_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['custom_meta2_nonce' ],basename( __FILE__)) ) ? 'true': 'false';
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
    //Exit scripts depending on save status
    if( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ){
        return;
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['sec_title'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id , 'sec_title', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'sec_title'] ) );
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['principle_duties'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id , 'principle_duties', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'principle_duties'] ) );
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'custom_meta2_save');
```

you can use custom page template file or page template file To display data in page:

```
$sec_title = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'sec_title', true );
$principle_duties = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'principle_duties', true);

echo "Secondary ID :".$sec_title;
echo "<br>Principle duties :".$principle_duties;
```

Comment: Thank you soo much !   Now if i write anything inside this title box and editor how can i show it in the front page ? please tell me

Comment: I have updated my answer to show data in page.

Comment: Thank you sooo much. :)